# How to catch exception if a webservice or a window service is down?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I know its silly but I want to know which Exception class to use in case webservice is down.I changes the url address of my webservice to something else, so that it throws the exception as **"There is no endpoint listing as...."**

Once I encountered the above record, it should be caught with a proper exception.

Below is the code that I used for Timeout exception. N now I want to handle an exception with no endpoint listed.

```
try
        {
            var result = proxy.Geocode(ADDRESSVERIFICATIONAPISOURCE);
            if (result != null)
            {
                // Display result of geocoding result.
                retAddresses.AddRange(
                    result.Select(
                        item =>
                        new AddressContent
                        {
                            Address = item.GeocodedAddress.Address,
                            City = item.GeocodedAddress.City,
                            State = item.GeocodedAddress.State,
                            Zip = item.GeocodedAddress.Zip,
                            Status = item.Status,
                            StatusFlag = item.StatusFlag,
                            SourceId = item.GeocodedAddress.SourceId
                        }));
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            retAddresses.AddRange(
                   addresses.Select(
                       item =>
                       new AddressContent
                       {
                           Status = null,
                           StatusFlag = item.StatusFlag,
                           SourceId = item.SourceId
                       }));
        }            
        catch
        {
            retAddresses.AddRange(
                    addresses.Select(
                        item =>
                        new AddressContent
                        {
                            Status = "N",
                            StatusFlag = item.StatusFlag,
                            SourceId = item.SourceId
                        }));
        }
//Here I want to handle exception if service is down
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What exception do you catch if the web service is down? If you're not sure, then why not try taking the web service offline and running your code and then seeing what exception you catch.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I used **EndpointNotFoundException** and it worked. Thank you for your help everyone.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd consider catching `CommunicationException`, which is more general than EndpointNotFoundException.